# How do I install a Theme in Keynote?

Tags: keynote

I just downloaded several themes that I want to use. They are in `/Library/Application Support/Keynote/Themes/` but I don't see them in the Theme Chooser screen.

Does anyone know what else I should be doing to install them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When you open a template or a common keynote file, you can use the option File → Save theme...
This puts your file in the necessary directory automatically and adds information about your theme to the welcome screen.

Answer (score 1):

Typically they should be in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iWork/Keynote/Themes/
```

You can copy yours there and they should show up; or when choosing a theme you can add them by navigating to the folder yours are in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is different in Keynote '09.  The method I found that works comes from https://discussions.apple.com/message/8789217#8789217

> It appears Apple has changed the way Keynote '09 accesses Themes.  If
>   you leave your 3rd party themes the way they were, Keynote '09 can't
>   seem to handle it and the theme chooser does not open or work
>   properly.
>
> Apple's standard themes are now imbedded in the package contents of
>   Keynote. (if you don't know what that means, don't worry. For those
>   that care opt click show package contents ...
>   Keynote>contents>resources>themes). You will have to find the third
>   party themes you want to use. They may be located in the library >
>   application support folder > iWork > Themes or somewhere like that
>   depending upon how you set it up before.
>
> Once you find the themes, I suggest moving them to a place like the
>   desktop or your documents folder.
>
> Once that has been done, Quit Keynote. Find the theme you want to
>   "import" Double click on it. Keynote '09 should open. Once it is open,
>   go to File>Save Theme.... you will be presented with the option to
>   name the theme and store it in a folder here
>   HD>Users>Home>Library>Application Support>iWork>Keynote>Themes.
>
> Once you have saved it, quit keynote. Open Keynote and go to the theme
>   chooser. Your new "imported" theme will be at the bottom after all of
>   the Apple standard themes.
>
> Repeat for each theme you want to import.

That might be overkill, but it did work for me.